# workspace.xml file corrupted (Error on line 1: Content is not allowed in prolog) in IntelliJ, how can I fix it?

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, ide

I am experimenting a very annoying issue using IntelliJ.

I was working on my project (a webapp deployed on a local instance of BEA weblogic application server) and suddenly my PC crash and I restarted it.

Coming back to my project I obtained this error:

> Cannot convert project: C:\projects\Main\MyProject\workspace.xml:
>   Error on line 1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

and looking inside the **workspace.xml** file of my project it contains something like it:

```
nulnulnulnulnul....
```

So, I delete it and I restart IntelliJ (I read onlyne that I have to do in this way) so IntelliJ create it and I can open my project again inside IntelliJ but now the problem is that I can't run it (the Run and Debug icons are disabled).

What could be the problem? and how can I try to solve this issue?

Tnx

Answer (score 34):

I experienced the same error. I deleted the workspace.xml and started 'Invalid Caches/Restart" under "File". Then I had to recreate my Run/Debug Configuration. Then everything works like before.

Comment: The "Invalid Caches/Restart" seemed to be the important step.

Comment: Delete all the files in .idea folder and use "Invalid Caches/Restart", it will generate the deleted files (no corrupted ones).

Answer (score 2):

I experienced same problem.you can solve it by deleting ant.xml, then everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the file encoding of the **workspace.xml** file was wrong. Converting it back to UTF-8 solved it for me.

Comment: How does one do that?